# Too many compiles when using latexmk with mpgraphics

Tags: compiling, latexmk, metapost

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mpgraphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
.
\label{fig:a}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{mpinline}
draw (20,20)--(0,0)--(0,30)--(30,0)--(0,0)
\end{mpinline}
\ref{fig:a}
\end{document}
```

I use MikTex 2.9 and TexMaker. I compiled this MWE with means of `latexmk`. To be more precise, the command was: `latexmk -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode/" -pdf %.tex`.

My document compiled over and over and over. A log says that:

```
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'C:/tmp/tmp-fig1.pdf' 'tmp-fig1.pdf' ------------ Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex' ------------ ------------ Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder "tmp.tex"' ------------

Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'C:/tmp/tmp-fig1.pdf' 'tmp-fig1.pdf' ------------ Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex' ------------ ------------ Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder "tmp.tex"' ------------

Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'C:/tmp/tmp-fig1.pdf' 'tmp-fig1.pdf' ------------ Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex' ------------ ------------ Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder "tmp.tex"' ------------

Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'C:/tmp/tmp-fig1.pdf' 'tmp-fig1.pdf' ------------ Run number 4 of rule 'pdflatex' ------------ ------------ Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder "tmp.tex"' ------------

Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'C:/tmp/tmp-fig1.pdf' 'tmp-fig1.pdf' ------------ Run number 5 of rule 'pdflatex' ------------ ------------ Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -recorder "tmp.tex"' ------------
```

Finally, it compiled five times which is 3 more than necessary.
I suspect the reason is that pdfs that are results of `mpinline` are not binary equal (they contain a timestamp or something like that?) and that causes latexmk to think that it needs to compile again.

When compiling very long document this behaviur is really annoying as it consumes a lot of time. 
Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really seems that the `.pdf` file is looked at for changes and of course it changes every time. On my experiment, `latexmk` actually gives up.

This works without problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
.
\label{fig:a}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
draw (20,20)--(0,0)--(0,30)--(30,0)--(0,0)
\end{mpost}
\ref{fig:a}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The generated `.pdf` file does indeed change every time, because of time stamps and the like.  (Just compared the generated `.pdf` file on successive runs.)  You can configure `latexmk` to ignore the relevant lines in the `.pdf` file(s) by putting the following in one of `latexmk`'s initialization files:

```perl
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = 
   '^/CreationDate\('
   .'|^/ModDate\('
   .'|^/ID \['
   .'|^<rdf:RDF '
   .'|^<rdf:Description rdf:about'
   .'|^<xmp:CreateDate>';
```