# texlatexmk and mVersion problem

Tags: latexmk

I've just run into a problem with `mVersion` and by extension `latexmk`. As users of `mVersion` know, it updates a file `version.dat` with each run of the **pdf/xe/lua/whatever** engine. Until I reached the point where I've added the indices and bibliography that was fine. Now however I'm looking at version.dat being changed three times in a single run (minimum of 3). That sadly puts `latexmk` in a loop and it errors out with:

```
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'version.dat'
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
Latexmk: All targets (Jourdan.pdf) are up-to-date
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'Jourdan':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Since I suspect I'm hardly the first to run into this problem, I'm looking to the forum for advice. I'm right now working through the 34-page manual in order to find how to add in my own post-processing (after the first run) Perl script. I'm guessing that creation of a `latexmkrc` file is part of the solution to several problems here, but I'm a bit out to sea at the moment regarding a solution.

Of course I can resort to a batch file (I'm running under Windows 7) and I will if I have to, but I'm hoping that I can get a leg up on a hardwired solution with `latexmk`.

tl;dr --- how do I stop shooting myself in the foot with `mVersion`. The side problem of running a Perl script in mid-stream I'll handle myself.

Comment: See if you can adapt John Collins' answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63076/too-many-compiles-when-using-latexmk-with-mpgraphics). Looks like the same basic problem. Alternatively, if you don't need a numeric version number, would a date/time stamp on the page suffice?

Comment: @MikeRenfro At the moment I've not be able to get latexmk to pay attention to a local latexmkrc file so I'm a little unsure of what to do next. It seemingly reads the file as I had several go-arounds with the cut and paste copy of the pdf file's (the 'manual' for latexmk) example of commands to place in the local latexmkrc file---took a bit to stamp out the incorrect single quote chars :) But after a clean read it failed to execute the lines there in! Still researching... Don't want date/time stamping, already have that with \date etc. Want version number similar to what I place in my software

Comment: @MikeRenfro was going to go on and say following the standard you normally get with --version at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mVersion}
\setVersion{1}
\increaseBuild
\begin{document}
\version
\end{document}
```

plus this latexmkrc

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'dat'} = '^[0-9]';
```

is working for me. Not sure why it wants to run `pdflatex` twice, but at least it's not in an infinite loop.

Comment: The two runs of `pdflatex` happen when you do an initial run of `latexmk`, modify the tex file, and then run `latexmk` again.  On the absolute first run of `pdflatex`, `latexmk` does not detect `version.dat` as a source file, since the file is written before being read. That changes on the run after the change in the tex file. Then `latexmk` reports that `version.dat` is changed or newly in use; it's the newly-in-use bit that triggers the extra run of `pdflatex`.  On later runs, the changes are only in the lines of `version.dat` that `latexmk` was told to ignore.

Comment: After thrashing about I've managed to effect the same solution. Excepting that I use `'^.*$` as my pattern. I've marked this as the answer. Now back to your regular programming...